# PID increments automatically

Tags: daemon, pid

I'm writing a init-script for a microservice and have the problem, that the PID of the process, that the program gives out (via echo) is not the process ID the process is having. The code:

```
#!/bin/bash

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: temp
# Description: temp
# required-start: $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# required-stop: $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# default-start: 3 5
# default-stop: 0 1 2 6
# chkconfig: 35 99 1
# description: Microservice init-script
### END INIT INFO

START_SCRIPT=${applicationDirectory}/script/start.sh
STOP_SCRIPT=${applicationDirectory}/script/stop.sh
PID_FILE=${runDirectory}/${microserviceName}_${environment}_${servicePort}

# ***********************************************
# ***********************************************

DAEMON=$START_SCRIPT

# colors
red='\e[0;31m'
green='\e[0;32m'
yellow='\e[0;33m'
reset='\e[0m'

echoRed() { echo -e "${red}$1${reset}"; }
echoGreen() { echo -e "${green}$1${reset}"; }
echoYellow() { echo -e "${yellow}$1${reset}"; }

start() {
  #PID=`bash ${START_SCRIPT} > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!`
  PID=`$DAEMON $ARGS > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!`
}

stop() {
    STOP_SCRIPT $1
}

case "$1" in
start)
    if [ -f $PID_FILE ]; then
        PID=`cat $PID_FILE`
        if [ -z "`echo kill -0 ${PID}`" ]; then
            echoYellow "Microservice is already running [$PID]."
            exit 1
        else
            rm -f $PID_FILE
        fi
    fi

    start

    if [ -z $PID ]; then
        echoRed "Failed starting microservice."
        exit 3
    else
        echo $PID > $PID_FILE
        echoGreen "Microservice successfully started [$PID]."
        exit 0
    fi
;;

status)
    if [ -f $PID_FILE ]; then
        PID=`cat $PID_FILE`
        if [ ! -z "`echo kill -0 ${PID}`" ]; then
            echoRed "Microservice is not running (process dead but pidfile exists)."
            exit 1
        else
            echoGreen "Microservice is running [$PID]."
            exit 0
        fi
    else
        echoRed "Microservice is not running."
        exit 3
    fi
;;

stop)
    if [ -f $PID_FILE ]; then
        PID=`cat $PID_FILE`
        if [ ! -z "`echo kill -0 ${PID}`" ]; then
            echoRed "Microservice is not running (process dead but pidfile exists)."
            exit 1
        else
            PID=`cat $PID_FILE`
            stop $PID
            echoGreen "Microservice successfully stopped [$PID]."
            rm -f $PID_FILE
            exit 0
        fi
    else
        echoRed "Microservice is not running (pid not found)."
        exit 3
    fi
;;

*)
    echo "Usage: $0 {status|start|stop}"
    exit 1
esac
```

Now, the program gives for example 2505 as PID. But when I use

```
ps aux | grep trans | grep -v grep
```

It outputs a number, that is the previously outputted number +1.

Can anyone give a guess? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If your service daemonizes itself by forking a child and then exiting then its  pid will be different to the parent launched by the start script. If you're on Linux then pid files are an anachronism that should be exterminated on sight. `/proc` is an OS maintained directory of pids that doesn't need to be duplicated by buggy start scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PID` variable gets the pid of the shell that executes `start.sh`.  The actual program executed by the script gets a different pid.

Comment: Thanks, that's just so obvious... -.-

Comment: Could you give me a small hint how I can get the PID from the process that is started in start.sh?

This doesn't work:

DAEMON=`nohup \${JAVA_EXEC} -jar \${MICROSERVICE_HOME}/bin/\${MICROSERVICE_JAR} server \${MICROSERVICE_CONF} 2>> /dev/null &
PID=\`\$DAEMON > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo \$!\`    
echo \$PID > \$PID_FILE"`